# Error parsing parameter '--expression-attribute-values': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am running the following query

```
aws dynamodb query `
--table-name user`
--key-condition-expression "datecreated = :d" `
--expression-attribute-values "{ ':d': { 'S': '2018-08-15' } }" --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Does dynamodb even understand what a double quote is?

1. I have tried swapping single quotes with double quotes.
2. Using double quotes everywhere
3. Doubling up the quotes, both single and double
4. Using slashes
5. Removing single quotes altogether

Comment: Not familiar with AWS Dynamodb, but how are you utilizing PowerShell in this?

Comment: @trebleCode: He's calling the `aws` utility from PowerShell (a script, presumably), as suggested by the tagging and also by the use of `\`` as the line-continuation character.

Comment: @trebleCode through the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two immediate problems:

- **`'` (single quotes) aren't valid string delimiters** in JSON; you **must use `"`** (double quotes):
- Sadly, as of v7.2 **PowerShell requires you to `\`-escape argument-internal `"` characters *when calling external programs***, *even though that **shouldn't be necessary***.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details, including a potential future (possibly opt-in) fix.
  - As an alternative to the manual `\`-escaping detailed below, you can use the **PSv3+ `ie` helper function** from the  **[`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native)** (in PSv5+, install with `Install-Module Native` from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Native)), which internally **compensates for all broken behavior** and allows passing arguments as expected; to use it, simply prepend `ie` to your invocations; e.g.:
    `ie aws dynamodb query ...`

Therefore, try this; note how **`'...'` is used for the *outer* quoting** (which PowerShell transforms to double quotes behind the scenes) so that you needn't escape `"` as `` `" `` inside the string - do note that the string content is then treated *literally*;
The `\`-escaping, however, is *always* needed when calling an external program such as `aws` as of PowerShell 7.2:

```
... --expression-attribute-values '{ \":d\": { \"S\": \"2018-08-15\" } }'
```

---

If you do need **`"..."` as the outer quoting** in order to use **string expansion** (interpolation), i.e., in order to embed variable references and expressions, things get uglier, because you need to apply *two* kinds of escaping: `` `" `` first, to satisfy PowerShell's syntax requirements, preceded by `\` to ensure the resulting embedded `"` are correctly passed through to the target program:

```
$date = [datetime]::now.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
... --expression-attribute-values "{ \`":d\`": { \`"S\`": \`"$date\`" } }"
```

---

A [**here-string**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) can ease the pain, but note that it invariably makes the command *multi-line* - and the need for `\`-escaping still applies (note that `"@`, the closing delimiter must not only be on its own line, it must be at the *very start* of that line):

```
... --expression-attribute-values @"
  { \":d\": { \"S\": \"$date\" } }
"@
```

Comment: I prefer the alternative option of using bash/ubuntu as the associated apps work better with docker

Answer (score 4):

I've gone through the same issue just now when using Key-Condition-Expression Parameter

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name mystore --key-condition-expression "clientid = :name" --expression-attribute-values '{":name":{"S":"chris@example.com"}}'
```

which would give

[image]

In order to solve it, just had to change the command to (note the `\"`)

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name mystore --key-condition-expression "clientid = :name" --expression-attribute-values '{\":name\":{\"S\":\"chris@example.com\"}}'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I wanted to create a bash script that accept an argument so that I can make a query with various input.

One way to avoid the problem was to use temporary json file.

In bash script:

```
attrvalues="{\":d\": {\"S\": \"$1\"}}"
echo "$attrvalues" > attr-values.json
```

which would create a file below if you provide `2021-01-31` as first input:

```
{
  ":d": {"S": "2021-01-31"}
}
```

Then in bash script:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name user \
    --key-condition-expression "datecreated = :d" \
    --expression-attribute-values file://attr-values.json \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000

rm attr-values.json
```

Answer (score 1):

It's frustrating that this doesn't work more simply.

I have always double converted the object to json, like this:

```
$cliValue = $myObjectGraph | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9 -Compress | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9;
```

Which gives me `$cliValue` in this form:

```
"{\"ids\":[[\"94143814-c212-41b1-983f-e2d8ff589b2a\",\"My Description 1\"],[\"418a5f04-3d5a-4516-961f-6b0ab448edbb\",\"My Description 2\"], ...
```